# Multilingual website testing - I am not able to type in French?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization, multilingual

I am creating a website using ASP.NET that supports multiple languages. For that I have created a local resource file for my login.aspx page. I want my login page in different languages like french, spanish etc.

For that I have also created two different resource file in my _LOCALRESOURCE folder in the solution explorer. Now in french local resource file I need to add the values in french language but I am not able to type in french in visual studio.

Do I have to install french font somewhere in the visual studio?

I have also saved the french local resource file as login.aspx.(language_name).resx.

Comment: Please explain "I am not able to type in French". Windows Western encompasses French.

Comment: if  i want to the form to appear in spanish i need to write the value in spanish resource file. So i am not able to type in spanish in my resource file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you type french outside the VS? if not; you need to activate the French keyboard for your windows
Go to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region --> keyboard and languages` then add the French keyboard

[image]

Comment: There is nothing special about French. Activating a layout for a different language changes some of the keys around, so I can't recommend that. Techniques like typing Alt+0234 might be less frustrating.

Comment: By changing this will i be able to type in french inside VS ?

Answer (score 1):

Once,have a look in following blog of MSDN:

[How to automatically configure Visual Studio IDE UI language for multi-lingual development](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/11/549592.aspx)

[Multi-lingual development support in the Visual Studio IDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/07/545919.aspx)